# Custom search from Geojson data in Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, json, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js

I have the India Geojson [file](https://github.com/sharseema/data/blob/master/State.geojson) on GitHub ,from that file i want to search the state name.I have saw the mapbox GL geocoder [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-local-geocoder/) but in this example where can i add the custom Geojson file for search,is it possible to add custom json file, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with that example. Refer to the API docs at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#mapboxgeocoder which say:

```
options.localGeocoder Function? A function accepting the query string which performs local geocoding to supplement results from the Mapbox Geocoding API. Expected to return an Array of GeoJSON Features in the Carmen GeoJSON format.
```

So you just need to convert your GeoJSON into Carmen GeoJSON https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/blob/master/carmen-geojson.md and then implement the function which matches your input query to results from your custom GeoJSON file.

Something like Bloodhound https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md could be used to provide the matches, or a simple regexp could work.

Comment: Thanks AndrewHarvey